# What is the solution to $x^2=y^2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What is the solution to $x^2=y^2$? I know it seems simple but I seem to have got myself all confused. Is this correct?

$$x^2=y^2$$
$$\pm\sqrt{x^2}=\pm\sqrt{y^2}$$
$$\pm x=\pm y$$
$$\Rightarrow x_{1}=y,\quad x_{2}=-y, \quad -x_{3}=y, \quad -x_{4}=-y$$
$$\iff x_{1}=x_{4}=y,\quad x_{2}=x_{3}=-y $$

Comment: I think it's better to write $x^2-y^2=0 \Rightarrow (x-y)(x+y)=0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$x^2 = y^2 \iff x^2 - y^2 = 0 \iff (x-y)(x+y) = 0$

A product is equal to $0$ if and only if one of its factors is equal to $0$

Thus:

$x^2 = y^2 \iff x - y = 0$ or $x + y =0 \iff x = -y$ or $x = y$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want a solution for  $y$ in terms of $x$,
$$ y= \pm x $$